# What is wrong with my application? and can you give me a good explanation

Tags: java

```
public class PersonName {


    int NumberNames(String wholename)
    {    // store the name passed in to the method
        String testname=wholename;
         // initialize number of names found
        int numnames=0;
         // on each iteration remove one name
        while (testname.length()>0)
        {   // take the "white space" from the beginning and end
           testname = testname.trim();
            // determine the position of the first blank
            // .. end of the first word
           int posBlank= testname.indexOf(' ');
          // cut off word
           testname=testname.substring(posBlank+1,testname.length());
          //  System.out.println(numnames);
          // System.out.println(testname);
           numnames++;
        }    
        return numnames;
    }


    public static void main(String args[])
    {
        PersonName One= new PersonName();

        System.out.println(One.NumberNames("Bobby"));
        System.out.println(One.NumberNames("Bobby Smith"));
        System.out.println(One.NumberNames("Bobby L. Smith"));
        System.out.println(One.NumberNames("  Bobby  Paul Smith Jr.  "));



    }
}
```

I cannot find whats wrong with the code. Please can you give me an explanation. im trying to debug this. I cannot find the issue. Im trying to fix the overall code

Comment: Please explain why do you think your code is wrong. What do you expect and what do you get?

Comment: This program is written with a loop that attempts to extract one name at a time from the string, counting the names as it progresses. When it removes all of the names, the loops stops... but it doesn't

Comment: `the loops stops... but it doesn't` I have no idea what this means.

Comment: Soooo, what would ever happen in the case that posBlank is -1 ? Can it happen? ;)

Comment: What's your expected output for all 4 cases?

Answer (score 2):

This code doesn't take into account the fact that `posBlank` can be `-1` if a space character isn't found in `testname`.  If it's `-1`, then this line is still executed:

```
testname=testname.substring(posBlank+1,testname.length());
```

The expression `posBlank+1` is `0`, so the string is unchanged.  This results in an infinite loop.

If `posBlank` is `-1`, then count that last word and break out of the `while` loop.

Comment: Correct. But I wonder if just giving out the answer is always the best option w.r.t. to teaching when it's about trivial things like this one :/ Is there any official guideline/stance on the matter that you know of?

Comment: @DiegoMartinoia For questions that look like homework, I guide the OP to the correct solution, but I don't give the actual code solution.

Comment: I see. Trying to find the best policy to apply myself :)

Answer (score 1):

The problem is if the space is not found, it will return -1

```
int posBlank= testname.indexOf(' ');
```

posBlank will become -1, resulting in `posBlank + 1 = 0` and it will cause the while loop to become an infinite loop

You can try it like this:

```
int NumberNames(String wholename)
    {    
        wholename = wholename.trim();
        String[] names = wholename.split(" ");
        int numNames = 0;

        for(String name : names){
            if(!name.equals("")){
                numNames++;
            }
        }
        return numNames;
    }
```